# How can I get variable from another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My case like this :

Html code (This is modal) :

```
<div class="modal-body">
    ...
    <input type="file" id="change-image" name="replace">
    ...     
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="confirm-edit-image">
        Save
    </button>    
</div>
```

If I click input type file, it will run the javascript code :

```
$('#change-image').change(function (e) {
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#change-image')[0].files[0]);
});
```

There exist variable data image

If I run this :

```
$('#confirm-edit-image').on("click",function(){
    // get variable data
});
```

I want to get the variable data image

How can I do it?

Comment: Are those functions in the same file? The faster approach is to globally declare `data` and the use it in your jquery callbacks

Comment: In the code shown, `data` is not a local variable so it's already accessible beyond the `change` handler, though obviously you do need to test its value in case it isn't set yet (if the user clicks the button before the file input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `data` outside those functions is enough to share the variable itself. Here's a live snippet.

For further details about variable scope in javascript, you can refer to this answer [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

```js
var data = new FormData();

$('#change-image').change(function (e) {
    data.append('file', $('#change-image')[0].files[0]);
});

$('#confirm-edit-image').on("click",function(){
    var empty = true;
    for (entry of data.entries()) {
      console.log(entry);
      empty = false;
    }
    if(empty) { console.log("Please add a file first!\n"); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    ...
    <input type="file" id="change-image" name="replace">
    ...     
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="confirm-edit-image">
        Save
    </button>    
</div>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined"`

Comment: Add a file before :)

Comment: And now it prints (in the console) a message if no files are provided

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that “data” is a global variable

```
var data;

$('#change-image').change(function (e) {
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#change-image')[0].files[0]);
});

$('#confirm-edit-image').on("click",function(){
    console.log(data);
});
```